# JwtBearer middleware not working with UseAuthorization

Tags: .net-core, jwt, bearer-token

I want existing expired tokens to be able to log in as well.

For that I wrote a middleware

```
using System;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Hoopt.Application.Infrastructure.Auth;
using Hoopt.Helper;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;

public class JwtExpirationMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public JwtExpirationMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _next = next;
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        // Token'ı al
        var token = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"].FirstOrDefault()?.Split(", ").Last().Replace("Bearer ", "");

        if (token != null)
        {
            try
            {
                var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_configuration["JwtConfig:Secret"].Sha256());

                var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true, // this will validate the 3rd part of the jwt token using the secret that we added in the appsettings and verify we have generated the jwt token
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), // Add the secret key to our Jwt encryption
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    RequireExpirationTime = false,
                    ValidateLifetime = false
                };


                var principal = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out SecurityToken validatedToken);

                context.User = principal;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (ex.Message.StartsWith("IDX10224"))
                {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Accepted;
                }
                else
                {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        await _next(context);
    }
}
```

And added startup.cs

```
 app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseMiddleware<JwtExpirationMiddleware>(Configuration);

            app.UseSentryTracing();

            app.UseCors("Default");
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/");
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
```

If I don't remove UseAuthorization, it gives a direct 401 error and doesn't fall into the middleware. If I remove it, it gives the following error. What should I do?

> Endpoint Hoopt.Api.Controllers.UserController.GetUserProfile (***) contains authorization metadata, but a middleware was not found that supports authorization.\nConfigure your application startup by adding app.UseAuthorization() inside the call to Configure(..) in the application startup code. The call to app.UseAuthorization() must appear between app.UseRouting() and app.UseEndpoints(...)

I want existing expired tokens to be able to log in as well.

Comment: `UseAuthentication` - `UseRouting` - `UseAuthorization` - `UseEndpoints`

Comment: Where should I add app.UseMiddleware<JwtExpirationMiddleware>(Configuration)? @Pieterjan

Comment: You don't need this custom middleware. You need to either set the `DefaultAuthenticationScheme` in the [`AddAuthentication`](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MintPlayer.Web/Startup.cs#L71) call, or set the scheme in the `[Authorize(AuthenticationScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]` on your [controller method](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MintPlayer.Web/Server/Controllers/Api/V1/AccountController.cs#L70)

Answer (score 0):

Your Authentication middleware occurs AFTER the Authorization.

You want to do

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseMiddleware<JwtExpirationMiddleware>(Configuration);
app.UseAuthorization();
```

This is because you want to Authenticate (work out who you are), before Authorize (work out if you are allowed in).

But as other commenters have pointed out, don't reinvent the wheel. I am certain your implementation contains subtile flaws like timing attacks.